# Removing "Optional" in Swift 4

Tags: swift

That's my code

```
let temperature = String(describing: Int(incomeTemp.text!))

celcjuszScore.text = "\(temperature)"
print(temperature)
```

Whent I am pushing a button, the result of print is "Optional(32)" (When I am writing 32 in incomeTemp). I would like to have "Optional" removed and only "32" should stay.

Comment: Why not just use the text as is, instead of converting it into an int and then immediately back into a string?

Comment: Side note: don't use `String(describing: xyz)` to make a string from an int, just use `String(xyz)`. The "describing" is actually the same as `xyz.description` which does not always represent the string content as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just unwrap it.

```
if let temperature = Int(incomeTemp.text!) {
    celcjuszScore.text = "\(temperature)"
    print(temperature)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the optional when converting text to number: `Int(incomeTemp.text!) ?? 0`.

Or solve the error explicitly:

```
if let temperature = Int(incomeTemp.text ?? "") {
   celcjuszScore.text = "\(temperature)"
} else {
   celcjuszScore.text = "Invalid temperature"
}
```